# accessing AVR registers with C?

Tags: c, pointers, avr, cpu-registers, avr-gcc

I've been trying to learn everything I can about micro-controllers lately. Since this is self-study, it's taken me a while to learn how the things work at the bare metal. Long story short, I don't want to use the AVR libraries in my C code; I want to access the registers specifically through their addresses using pointers in C. I've searched **everywhere** online, looked inside the AVR header files, and read a book. If someone could help me out that would be wonderful.

Comment: so, what's wrong with `PORTB = 0xff;`? If you don't like the name `PORTB` (for some obscure reason), then you can just go to `<avr/io.h>` and look at the address it's defined to, then write `*(volatile uint8_t *)0xbadf00d = 0xff;`

Comment: Somewhat less heinously, there is `char * portbptr = & PORTB;`.

Comment: With which compiler? You should be able to access registers with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Notably using [GCC extensions to C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html)

Comment: Holandaise, could you clarify if you already know how to access the register directly doing something normal like `PORTB = 0xFF`?  Do you specifically want to use pointers or do just want to write to the register in any way?

Comment: If you look into your header files, you'll see that PORTB and similars are just macros, like `#define ADMUX (*(unsigned char *) 0x7c)`

Answer (score 5):

You can cast from an integer to a pointer. It's just a normal cast expression.

```
volatile char * const port_a = (volatile char *) 0x1B;
```

Many compilers provide extensions to instruct the linker to place an object at a specific address:

```
volatile char port_a @ 0x1B; // Or something like this
```

The advantage is that you don't introduce a global variable to represent the pointer, but it might not do the right thing for a hardware register. You need to read carefully your compiler's manual for your specific platform.

The official AVR headers probably contain something more like this:

```
#define PORTA (* (volatile char *) 0x1B)
```

This avoids the global variable and the linker hack, but many also consider using the preprocessor also to be hacking.

The only viable solution for production code is to use the official headers. Anything else is only instructional.

Comment: Also, you can write something like `&PORTB` instead of 0x1B which makes the code more portable and easier to understand.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes, I said that in the question comments. But, I'm not sure it really scratches the OP's itch.

Comment: Care must be taken to only use PORTs and other specific register (timers, etc.) in this way. Using a general purpose register might lead to nasty surprises if the compiler automatically assigned another variable to it, or uses it as a local temporary storage.

Comment: @vsz CPU registers are usually not memory-mapped. "Register" in this sense refers to flip-flops in a peripheral device which are accessible via the data bus.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : No, in AVR (at least in their ATtiny and ATmega series) **all** CPU registers are memory-mapped. http://www.avr-tutorials.com/sites/default/files/Memory%20Map%20Small.jpg

Comment: @vsz OK, I looked at a block diagram and memory map but didn't pick that up. I wonder why they did that; it sounds like it would make hardware implementation more difficult with no programming benefit. Anyway, you can still think of that as the general-purpose register file having a peripheral device interface to the data bus.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : probably because they have internal SRAM. If they already have it, it might make sense to use the same mechanics to access it. The whole registers + internal SRAM seems to be like what larger CPUs have as cache.

Comment: @vsz Nah, internal SRAM is a defining feature of all microcontrollers. A register file is also just a specialized form of SRAM. Combining the register file and RAM into one unit is bound to waste a lot of power and severely limit architectural scalability. Maybe it was a good idea for a prototype, but in the long run it's as bad for the hardware as it is for the programming model.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much depends on the compiler, some use a stricter interpretation of the `register` keyword.

For example,

`unsigned char a @0x0001;` will put the variable into the specific register.

Otherwise, you could just assign numeric values to your pointers, it's a big no-no if your program runs in an OS, but if you have a guaranteed physical memory which you know the boundaries of, it might be acceptable. However, care must be taken that the compiler does not use that register automatically, which is a hard thing to make sure unless you write most of your code in Assembly.

So, the variable declaration method (if your compiler supports it) is the better choice, as it guarantees that no other variable will take up its place.

Comment: That's not portable at all. At least mention which compiler that's for.

Comment: CodeVision allows strict variable declaration unto a general purpose register, and guarantees that the register will not be used for other purposes. It still should only be used if you are *really* sure you know what you are doing, as you take away a general purpose register from the compiler, who might be able to use it in a much more optimal way.

Comment: Then the semantic is *reserving* a register, not just accessing it. Probably the allocation is done by the linker, like my answer mentions.